# Evenly spacing out elements within a div for responsive design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have four elements within a div and want to space them out evenly in the available space. What technique is considered best practice for responsive design in this case?

For each element, I am using:

```
height: 75px;
width: 75px;
border-radius: 50%;
margin-right: 20px;
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adnanymous/9yYZJ/

Comment: These answers seem old now. Must be a better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're already using bootstrap, just insert a `div.row-fluid` inside that div that should contain the four items. Wrap each of those four items in a `div.span3`. That will auto scale the spacing until you get down before 767px wide (bootstrap's phone size), at which point everything will stack vertically. This avoids adding extra libraries and needs will work even without javascript enabled.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span3">Thing1</div>
  <div class="span3">Thing2</div>
  <div class="span3">Thing3</div>
  <div class="span3">Thing4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou! I am using Bootstrap 3 though, and found in their documentation the use of sx, sm, lg prefixes for this. Your solution is however fine for Bootstrap 2, and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Flexboxes (http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/) do exactly what you want, if you can live with the current state of browser support (http://caniuse.com/flexbox) and the need to use vendor prefixes. In your case, something like this:

```
#my-div {
    display: -webkit-flex;        
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-between; /* flush against edges */
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-around;  /* space at left/right */
}

.elt {
    -webkit-flex: none; /* do not grow and shrink items */
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

These are responsive by nature. Certainly better than some flaky jQuery plugin.