# Evenly spaced logos using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap 3, how can I create a single row of evenly spaced logos? The logos are simple JPG images, and I'm currently using code like this:

```
<table class="logotable text-center">
     <tr>
        <td>
          <img ..>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>

.logotable {
   width: 100%
}
```

Even though this looks great on PC, it does not convert to stacked form for smaller screen devices.

Whatever I tried didn't work (the logos always appear in stacked form)

- For some reason [row-fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18285295/1294758) or [container-fluid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid) doesn't work (my parent container cannot be fluid since I also need some text within the container)
- I tried placing a `div.row-fluid` within my container and adding every image inside a `div.row` but that didn't work
- I don't want to ["hard code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702545/bootstrap-3-11-evenly-spaced-columns) for a fixed number of columns
- After [lots of confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22263969/1294758) I realized I don't need a container-fluid, ie. it does not evenly space out rows, instead it just expands to fill the available space

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a <table> instead of a <div>?

Comment: I would use a div but the bootstrap version does not work. Therefore right now I'm using plain-HTML awaiting help with bootstrap.

Comment: Tables are for tabular data, a row of evenly spaced logos is not tabular data.

Comment: @APAD1 - That comment is neither meaningful nor helpful. We are discussing practical ways to achieve something here. If you have a tip, add an answer. Don't just fire off your personal policies that are impossible to always follow.

Comment: Yes it is both meaningful and helpful. In your question you posted HTML for a table and I am telling you that this is not the correct situation to use a table. It is not a "personal policy" it is the generally accepted best practice for this day and age.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `col-[breakpoint]-[columns]` as well as the `row` div, which is probably why it didn't work when you tried it.

In addition to that, in Boostrap 3 you need to use the `img-responsive` class on images to make them responsive.

`row-fluid` was used in Bootstrap 2 I believe and deprecated in Bootstrap 3.

I'm not sure how many logos you want on one row, but you could do something like the following to have 3 images on one line:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="/path/to/image" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="/path/to/image" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="/path/to/image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

To avoid hardcoding, you could use flexbox like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="" alt="1" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="" alt="2" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="" alt="3" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="" alt="4" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="" alt="5"class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* to center flex-items */
.flex-item {
   margin: auto;
}
```

[Non-Centered Items Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z19ar1nL/) | [Centered Items Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z19ar1nL/1/)

[Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**UPDATE**

To vertically centre the flexbox items, just add a height to the container:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: auto;
}
```

[Vertically Centred Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z19ar1nL/2/)

Comment: Since we have `col-md-4`, is that not hard coding for the number of logos? I want a way to add any number of logos without calculating the `col-*`. Currently I have 5 logos, so its a wierd number and does not work with the 12 col system.

Comment: it's hardcoding yes, if you didn't want to do that then flexbox would be an option.

Comment: Does flexbox play well with bootstrap? Is there a quick start guide somewhere? I want `flex-grow` with `justify-content = space-between` and `align-items = center`. Flexbox is a JS/CSS lib or is it just a spec? I want my thing to work well on older/all browsers not just the latest.

Comment: Hi, flexbox should be fine with bootstrap, I've updated my answer and there's a fiddle there too.

Comment: Wow. It works amazing. Just one last snag... the images are all aligned to TOP. Is there a way to align the images to the V-CENTER of the row? I checked with the inspected and the flex-items are correctly sized (h and w) its just the images that are not centered vertically to the flex items.

Comment: vertical-align css property ?

Comment: @Geotarget - answer updated with new fiddle, give that a try?

Answer (score 1):

What are the requirements? How many logos per line? Is that should be centered/justified?

If not you can just write/generate div with the class `col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1` for instance that contain each icon and you will have what you want.

With those classes you'll be able to get 4 icon per line on mobile, 6 on tablets, 12 otherwise.

Let me know if it's not enough

EDIT:

So 5 icons per line, a grid is 12 column per line, let's centered it and skip the 1st column. So we get:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><img ... /></div>
     <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><img ... /></div>
     <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><img ... /></div>
     <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><img ... /></div>
     <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><img ... /></div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><img ... /></div>
     <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><img ... /></div>
     <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><img ... /></div>
     <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><img ... /></div>
     <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><img ... /></div>
</div>
```

Some technical (and not very mastered by me) points: 
`col-sm-*` apply for tablets : so this code will display 5 icons per line from tablet up to large desktop.
`col-xs-*` : for mobile so 1 icon per line

The `clearfix`: I'm not sure about this but it's useful when you don't ended your last container with just 12 column so better to use it from 2nd div. You can even you it from 1 div, it won't cause trouble as fair as I know.

If the division of the row cause some extra space, you can either remove it by using some style attribute or CSS classes.

Comment: 5 logos per line. 1 line/row. They should all show in one line on PC and be stacked on mobile. How do I do this?

Comment: answer edited does it seems good for you ? You can test in your broswer jus resize your window until to get less than 300px of width

Comment: Thanks for helping, but martincarlin87's answer worked for me. I don't want to hard-code.